# Converting large number to date giving unexpected results in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting a JSON body back from a restful service. One of the data is Paid_at: 1696484073 (num). I need to turn that into a date.

Ive tried:

```
SELECT TO_timestamp( '1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) + NUMTODSINTERVAL( nvl(l_payment_date,0), 'SECOND' )
into l_payment_date_trans 
FROM DUAL;
```

returns 10/05/23 and thats not right

```
l_payment_date_str := to_char(l_payment_date);
l_payment_date_trans := TO_DATE(to_char(l_payment_date_str), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

didnt work

```
SELECT TO_DATE(to_char(l_payment_date_str), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
into l_payment_date_trans 
FROM DUAL;
```

returns 03/02/15 and I dont think thats right.

How can I take that number ('l_payment_date') into a date and assign the value to l_payment_date_trans?

Comment: How do you know that either of those dates are wrong? You say definitively that 10/05/2023 is not right, but you're not sure whether 03/02/15 is right or not. How can you say that it is or isn't working when you don't know what the correct value would be?

Comment: The unix date 1696484073  is indeed 2023-10-05 05:34:33

Comment: Your first attempt is the recommended way to convert the unix date.

Comment: Except really it should be `timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + ...` and you can then convert the resulting UTC time to another zone if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use SQL and can do it all in PL/SQL.

Additionally, the epoch time is from midnight 1970-01-01 in the UTC time zone so you want to use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_payment_date       NUMBER := 1696484073;
  l_payment_date_trans TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE;
BEGIN
  l_payment_date_trans := TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
                            + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * l_payment_date;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(l_payment_date_trans, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR'));
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 2023-10-05 05:34:33 UTC
> ```

---

Apart from not being in the UTC time zone, your first solution is correct:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_payment_date       NUMBER := 1696484073;
  l_payment_date_trans TIMESTAMP(0);
BEGIN
  l_payment_date_trans := TO_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                            + NUMTODSINTERVAL(NVL(l_payment_date,0), 'SECOND');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(l_payment_date_trans, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 2023-10-05 05:34:33
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a68XNojo)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that value you got isn't right? Because you didn't see time component? Well, maybe that's about your *client* which is currently set to display only date value. If you set it correctly (like following example shows), you'll see that it - actually - is right.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6';

Session altered.

SQL> select date '1970-01-01' + (&&your_value / 86400 ) result_date,
  2         --
  3         timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + numtodsinterval (&your_value, 'second' ) result_timestamp
  4  from dual;
Enter value for your_value: 1696484073

RESULT_DATE         RESULT_TIMESTAMP
------------------- --------------------------------------------------
05.10.2023 05:34:33 05.10.2023 05:34:33.000000

SQL>
```